# A question about Exercise 2.11 from Atiyah's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

The exercise is as follows:

> Supposing $A$ is a commutative ring with an identity, if $A \ne 0$ and $A^m \cong A^n$, then $m=n$.

I have some question with the proof.
The proof is as follows:

> Assume $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$ which $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal in $A$.
>
> If $\phi \colon A^m \rightarrow A^n$ is the $A$-module isomorphism, so I get
> $$\mathrm{id}_k \otimes \phi \colon k \otimes_A A^m \rightarrow k \otimes_A A^n$$
> is the group isomorphism. $(*)$.
>
> Because $$k_A \otimes_A A^m \cong \oplus_m (k_A \otimes_A A) \cong \oplus_m k \cong k^m, \quad k \otimes A^n \cong \oplus_n k \cong k^n, $$
>
> $\mathrm{id}_k \otimes \phi$ is an isomorphism between vector spaces of dimensions $m$ and $n$ over the field $k$.
>
> Thus $m = n$.

My question is:

From $(*)$, the isomorphism is a group isomorphism and how to get it is also a $k$-module isomorphism?

Is it simply by definition
$l \times v_2 = (\mathrm{id}_k \otimes \phi)(l \times v_1)$ with $l \in k$, $v_2 = (\mathrm{id}_k \otimes \phi)(v_1)$, $v_1 \in k^m$, $v_2 \in k^n$?

Assume $\mathrm{id}_k \otimes \phi = f$, and $l, l_1 \in k$.

1. $l (v_2 + v_{2'}) = l (f(v_1 + v_{1'})) = f(l v_1 + l v_{1'}) = f(l v_1) + f(l v_{1'}) = l f(v_1) + l f(v_{1'})$.
2. $(l + l_1) v_2 = (l + l_1) f(v_1) = f(l v_1) + f(l_1 v_1) = lv_2 + l_1 v_2$.
3. $l (l_1 v_2) = l f(l_1 v_2) = f(l \cdot l_1 v_2)$.
4. $1 v_2 = f(1 v_1) = v_2$.

Using $f$ is the group isomorphism, I check it and I think it is true.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $kv_2$?

Comment: I edited it.  $k^m$ is a $k$-module, $k^m$ and $k^n$ have a group isomorphismbetween them. I want to extend it to be a $k$-module isomorphism. Thus I want to define  $k$ atcs on $k^n$. $k$ is a field.

Comment: Since we have the natural quotient map from $A \rightarrow k$, $k \otimes_{A} A^m$ has a $k$-module structure(i.e. a $k$-vector space). I think you are confusing yourself by considering these as $\mathbb{Z}-A$ bimodules or whatever. Since we are over commutative ring, these are all $A$-bimodules (and $k$-bimodules after taking the tensor product). $id_k \otimes \phi$ is actually a $k$-vector space isomorphism.

Comment: @ user600016  Thanks, I know $k\otimes A^m$ has a $k$-module structure. Firstly, I get $\mathbb{id}_k\otimes \phi$ is just a group isomorphism. I want to extend it to be a $k$-module isomorphism. Maybe I have checked the above definition is also a  $k$-module isomorphism.